# Program based on Vigenère’s cipher

Tags: beginner, c, vigenere-cipher

I would like to get some helpful thoughts on this and if there is a way to break it. Is there any point to not use `fgets` in that form?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define GETNAME_SIZE 100

char *getPhrase() {

    int size;
    char phrase[GETNAME_SIZE];
    char *phraseHolder;
    printf("Enter a phrase:");

    fflush(stdout);

    if (fgets(phrase,sizeof phrase,stdin) == NULL ) {
        return NULL;
    }

    size = strlen(phrase)+1;
    phraseHolder = malloc(size);
    if (phraseHolder == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    strcpy(phraseHolder,phrase);
    phraseHolder[strcspn(phraseHolder,"\n")] = '\0';
    printf("The phrase you introduced is: <%s>\n", phraseHolder);

    return phraseHolder;

}

char *getChangedPhrase(char *phrase) {

    int size,i,codeSize;
    int j = 0;
    char *code;
    int pace;
    size = strlen(phrase)+1;
    if(size <2) {
        printf("Enter a bigger phrase!");
        return NULL;
    }


    code = malloc(size);
    if (code == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    fflush(stdout);
    printf("Enter the code that you want to be used with your phrase!(only letters)\n");

    if (fgets(code,size,stdin) == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    code[strcspn(code,"\n")] = '\0';
    codeSize = strlen(code);
    for(i = 0 ; i < size ; i++) {
            if(phrase[i] < 65 || (90 < phrase[i] && phrase[i] < 97) || 122<phrase[i] ) {
                continue;
            }
            else {
                while(code[j] < 65 || (code[j] > 90 && code[j] < 97) || code[j] > 122 ) {
                    j++;
            }
                pace = code[j];

            if(code[j] > 96 && code[j] < 123) {
            pace = pace - 97;

            if(phrase[i] + pace > 122 )
                phrase[i] = phrase[i] + pace - 26;
            else
                if( phrase[i] + pace > 90 && code[j] < 90)
                phrase[i] = phrase[i] + pace - 26;
            else
                if(phrase[i] + pace > 90 && code[j] > 96 && phrase[i] < 91 ) {
                   phrase[i] = phrase[i] + pace - 26;
                }
            else
                phrase[i] = phrase[i] + pace;


        }
            else if ( code[j] > 64 && code[j] <91 ) {
                pace = pace - 65;

                if((phrase[i] < 91 && (phrase[i] + pace) > 90) || (phrase[i] + pace) > 122 )
                    phrase[i] = (phrase[i] + pace - 26);

                else
                    phrase[i] = phrase[i] + pace;
            }

            j++;

            if(j == codeSize) {
                j = 0;
            }
        }

    }
    free(code);
    phrase[strcspn(phrase,"\n")] = '\0';
    return phrase;
}


int main() {
    char *phrase = getPhrase();
    char *modifiedPhrase = getChangedPhrase(phrase);
    printf("The changed phrase is: \n <%s> \n", modifiedPhrase);
    //free(phrase);
    printf("Press ENTER key to Continue\n");
    getchar();
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: I have now posted a review, so please stop with the code changes.  In the future, please do not post code for review until it's actually *ready* for review.  That you felt the need to make so many substantive code changes indicates to me that it was *not* ready when you first posted it.  For the record, although you couldn't know at the time that I was working on a review, your series of changes did interfere with my efforts.

Comment: @PellMel Yes it won't happen again, i learned today to at least test for the output of every case. That was hard probably because of the way i made this, but i finally think i go everything. Sorry for this and thank you for your review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is pretty clean and well-formed, but I do have several critiques.

#### Unexpected behavior

Your program will exhibit unexpected behavior if the phrase entered by the user is longer than `GETNAME_SIZE - 2` chars.  In that cases, the `fgets()` call in `getPhrase()` will leave the tail of the line unread, and reading should be expected to pick up there in the subsequent `getChangedPhrase()` call (to terminate no later than the end of that line).  The user will no doubt expect the phrase to be encoded according to the *next* line they enter, not the tail of the first.

To fix that, you should either arrange in `getPhrase()` to keep reading through the end of the line.  You can discard characters after the `GETNAME_SIZE - 1`<sup>th</sup> if you like, or you can arrange to append them to the phrase (you'll need `realloc()`).  Just don't leave a tail of the line unread.

`getChangedPhrase()` behaves similarly when it reads the key, which again could be surprising.  It is not certain to be sufficient to limit the input key length to the message length because you don't necessarily use all of the key characters (you skip those that aren't ASCII letters).  Cutting off the tail of the key can therefore change the result.

This fragment looks wrong:

```
                if( phrase[i] + pace > 90 && code[j] < 90)
                phrase[i] = phrase[i] + pace - 26;
```

I think you mean

```
                if( phrase[i] + pace > 90 && phrase[i] < 91)
                phrase[i] = phrase[i] + pace - 26;
```

See also below.

#### Flawed implementation

Your code can easily be made to overrun the bounds of the `code` array.  In fact, that *will* happen if the number of usable key characters is smaller than the number of letters in the message.  To (partially) fix this, you need to wrap around the end of the key inside the `while` loop, rather than at the end of the `for` loop where you now do that.

That will, however, expose another flaw in your implementation: it does not handle the case where there are zero usable key characters.  Your current implementation will just immediately run off the end of the array in that case; after the fix, it will loop infinitely.  See below for a suggestion that will help.

#### Error handling

`getPhrase()` does a decent job of noticing when memory allocation fails or nothing is read from the input.  It helpfully returns `NULL` in those cases.  `main()`, however, ignores those signals and unconditionally passes the result to `getChangedPhrase()`.  For its part, `getChangedPhrase()` assumes that its argument is always valid.  Either `main()`'s behavior or `getChangedPhrase()`'s could be ok in isolation, but together they constitute a flaw producing undefined behavior under some circumstances.

Similarly, `getChangedPhrase()` returns `NULL` in some failure conditions, but `main()` pays no attention, assuming that the return value is a valid pointer, in attempting to print it.

#### Implementation improvement

If you have `strdup()` (which is standardized by POSIX, not C itself) then it is a convenient alternative to `strlen()` + `malloc()` + `strcpy()`.

`getChangedPhrase()` calls `fflush(stdout);` *before* prompting for the encoding key.  This is useless.  Move the flush after the prompt, or remove it altogether.  Since the prompt ends with a newline, it is probably unnecessary to flush even after printing the prompt.

I remarked above on problems with your key handling.  I observe also that you handle your key inefficiently if it is short relative to the phrase to encode.  You shouldn't need to check on each pass through the key which characters are usable.  You shouldn't need to account for upper- vs. lowercase on each pass, either, if indeed you make them behave the same way.  Instead, process the key once, before the encoding loop: remove characters other than letters, and convert all the letters to a standard case.  Then it's also easy to validate result to ensure that there is at least one (or two, or whatever) key characters.

It doesn't make sense to me that your encoding code is not parallel for upper- and lowercase key characters.  The code for uppercase keys looks equally applicable to lowercase keys except the computation of `pace`, but you use a more complicated and difficult to follow scheme for lowercase key characters.  Indeed, one of the alternatives for lowercase keys cannot even be exercised, because `code[j] < 90` and `code[j] > 96` cannot be true at the same time.

#### Design improvement

Your function `getChangedPhrase()` modifies the input string in-place, but also returns a pointer to it.  On the other hand, the function's name suggests that it will create a new phrase.  I suggest changing that function's signature to

```
void encodePhrase(char *);
```

to clarify what it's doing.  If you wish to have the ability to signal an error, then you could consider using an `int` return value to signal the status, following the model of many standard library functions.